# PHP Replace EM Dash REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace this character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm 
with a regular dash , this is what i have yet i cant seem to get it to work?

```
$dataold = "9am – 5pm"; // from a ms word doc

$data = mb_ereg_replace("[\xE2 \x80 \x94]", " - ", $dataold);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Problem: your example code has an "N" dash.  You're asking for an "M" dash.  The code you're using works just fine for an "M" dash so long as you remove the whitespace in the RegEx.

Comment: Do you just want to normalize all dashes to a `space-space`? I think you may just use `preg_replace('~\p{Pd}~u', ' - ', $s)`. Else, just use `str_replace('—', ' - ', $s)` for EM-DASH and `str_replace('–', ' - ', $s)` for EN-DASH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother with the octal unicode format?  Why not...

**Replace an N-Dash**

```
$dataold = "9am – 5pm"; // from a ms word doc
$data = mb_ereg_replace(" – ", " - ", $dataold);
print_r($data);
```

**Replace an M-Dash**

```
$dataold = "9am — 5pm"; // from a ms word doc
$data = mb_ereg_replace(" — ", " - ", $dataold);
print_r($data);
```

Your original code works fine, except the sample text string has an N-dash and you're testing for an M-dash.  (And you have extra spaces in your RegEx).  Try this...

```
$dataold = "9am — 5pm"; // from a ms word doc
$data = mb_ereg_replace("[\xE2\x80\x94]", " - ", $dataold);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Because it would be hard to maintain if there are any unicode chars in the string. Using the right codes would clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dataold = "9am – 5pm"; // from a ms word doc
$data = mb_ereg_replace("/ \\x{2014} /u", " - ", $dataold);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: hmm no luck :/ .

Comment: Still getting the same thing out :/

Comment: Ok, then what about this one?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working but — character copied directly from the page you pasted (copying from your code didn't work).

```
<?php
$dataold = "9am — 5pm"; // from a ms word doc
$data = mb_ereg_replace("\x{2014}", "dash", $dataold);
print_r($data); // output = 9am dash 5pm
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/9Lkpr