# php Cannot replace em dash

Tags: php, replace

I am scraping a html page and working with the contents. My page is UTF-8 as is the page I am scraping.
I have looked at this question, but it does not work for me.
[PHP Replace EM Dash REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748176/php-replace-em-dash-regex)

The piece of data I am reading is this which is stored in $v

```
 25th March –Â The Red Barn
```

I need to remove the special characters between March and The.
Looking in a hex editor, the first character is an em dash : E2 80 93

I have tried this as suggested in the question above, but it does not remove character.

```
$v = mb_ereg_replace("[\xE2\x80\x93]", "", $v);
```

I cannot remove the other character either : C3 82
I suspect this is for the same reason.

Please help.

Comment: You're either displaying UTF8 data as ISO8859-1, or you've forced an encoding conversion that you shouldn't have. Post the output of `bin2hex($v);` and I can better pin down which way you've munged your data.

Answer (score -1):

This will get it done:

```
<?php
$v = "25th March –Â The Red Barn";
$result = str_replace("–Â", "", $v);
echo $result;
```

While this is what you asked for, please notice that it will result in a double space between "March" and "The" so you may want to then remove double spaces (if you care) with:

```
$new_result = str_replace("  ", " ", $result);
echo $new_result;
```